# Correct BigInt Fibonacci Implementation in Zig Lang

Tags: memory, biginteger, allocator, zig

I am new to Zig Lang, and I was searching for an existing implementation for Big Int Fibonacci to no avail.

So, I went through the source code of Zig Lang, Specifically [Big Int Source](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/905c85be968e6823305887474d2a821dac82f16c/lib/std/math/big/int.zig) & [Big Int Tests](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/905c85be968e6823305887474d2a821dac82f16c/lib/std/math/big/int_test.zig), to figure out how to use the Big Int functionality and then winged the desired solution.

It's sort of a tradition I follow while trying to gauge the speed of a language before learning. Like I did with: [Big Int Fibonacci Benchmark for Go & Rust](https://gist.github.com/callerobertsson/67b674d996a65b5e9b00#gistcomment-3877531). (N.B. I didn't have to write the solution for those languages!)

Now, here's my implementation in Zig, for your kind perusal:

```
const std = @import("std");
const Managed = std.math.big.int.Managed;

pub fn main() anyerror!void {
    // var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.c_allocator);
    // defer arena.deinit();
    // const allocator = arena.allocator();

    const allocator = std.heap.c_allocator;

    var a = try Managed.initSet(allocator, 0);
    defer a.deinit();
    var b = try Managed.initSet(allocator, 1);
    defer b.deinit();
    var i: u128 = 0;

    while (i < 50000) : (i += 1) {
        var c = try Managed.init(allocator);

        try c.add(a.toConst(), b.toConst());

        a = b;
        b = try c.clone();

        c.deinit();
    }

    const as = try a.toString(allocator, 10, std.fmt.Case.lower);
    defer allocator.free(as);
    std.log.info("Fib: {s}", .{as});
}
```

If I try to increase the number to 500,000, the memory usage increases to over 10 GB.

I want the program to run without memory leak for n =

```
    50,000 (Runs fine, with Arena & General Purpose Alloc!)
   500,000 (Mem Leak)
 1,000,000 (Mem Leak)
 5,000,000 (Mem Leak)
10,000,000 (Mem Leak)
```

I tried most of the allocators, `page_allocator, ArenaAllocator, GeneralPurposeAllocator`, to speed up the process and arrived at `c_allocator`. As for how to plug the memory leak, I have no clue!

P.S. I have just skimmed the documentation of ZigLang & ZigLearn to get to this point. I have no grasp of the entire language. So please go easy on me!

P.P.S. Command I used to build the app:

```
zig build-exe ./src/main.zig -O ReleaseFast --strip -lc
```

System Info: Mac Mini 2020, base variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the solution: (Using inbuilt swap method for efficient memory swaps!)

```rs
const std = @import("std");
const Managed = std.math.big.int.Managed;

pub fn main() anyerror!void {
    const allocator = std.heap.c_allocator;

    var a = try Managed.initSet(allocator, 0);
    defer a.deinit();
    var b = try Managed.initSet(allocator, 1);
    defer b.deinit();
    var i: u128 = 0;

    var c = try Managed.init(allocator);
    defer c.deinit();

    while (i < 1000000) : (i += 1) {
        try c.add(a.toConst(), b.toConst());

        a.swap(&b); // This is more efficient than using Clone!
        b.swap(&c); // This reduced memory leak.
    }

    const as = try a.toString(allocator, 10, std.fmt.Case.lower);
    defer allocator.free(as);
    std.log.info("Fib: {s}", .{as});
}
```

Using this, the memory usage went upto 3.4 mb, max, for n = 1,000,000!!

But it took a minute to finish, far slower than Rust or Golang!

P.S. I created an issue on Git: [Super slow Big Int Implementation in Zig](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/10630)

Comment: What happens if you just create `c` outside of the loop like you did for `a` and `b`?

Comment: It didn't speed up by any margin. After trying out these kinds of code re arrangements, I raised a bug in GitHub. The slow part turned out to be the toString method in the end!! https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/10630

Comment: Actually, it reduced memory usage by a bit. Thank you. Hope you don't mind me updating my code a bit based on your suggestion.

Comment: Of course not, please do.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your original code, you seem to leak `a` at every loop. You need to free it before assigning `b` to it, I think.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const std = @import("std");
const print = std.debug.print;

pub fn main() !void {
    var a: i16 = 0;
    var b: i16 = 1;
    var nextnum: i16 = 0;
    var n: i16 = 10000;

    print("{},{},", .{ a, b });
    nextnum = a + b;
    while (nextnum <= n) {
        print("{},", .{nextnum});
        a = b;
        b = nextnum;
        nextnum = a + b;
    }
    print("\n", .{});
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the OP question in any way. OP wants to use a `BigInt` type, yet `i16` is not only a fixed width, it is significantly more narrow than typical default integer types. Additionally, answers should almost always provide some explanation or discussion; code-only answers are rarely appropriate.